# Does this set-theoretic construction have a name?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

Suppose I am given a set $A$ and an ideal $J$ on $A$, and I express $A$ as a union of sets in $J$, that is,

$$A = \bigcup_{\gamma\in \Gamma} A_\gamma$$

where $\Gamma$ is some index set and each $A_\gamma$ is in $J$.

I get an ideal $I$ on the index set $\Gamma$ by the following formula:

$X\in I$ if and only if $\bigcup_{\gamma\in X}A_\gamma\in J$.

Is there some terminology already in use that describes the relationship between $I$ and $J$?   I've been mentally calling $I$ the *shadow* of $J$ on the index set, but wondering if something this basic already has a name. Note that I do not assume that the sets $A_\gamma$ are disjoint; if that occurs we can describe things using the vocabulary of the Rudin-Keisler ordering and its variations.